# Can I use audio file for offline Speech to text in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, speech-to-text

I am successfully able to run offline speech to text model in android studio by using SpeechRecognizer and RecognizerIntent classes. But my problem is, I first want to record audio, do some post-processing on audio file and then I want speech to text results by passing that audio file.
Note: I do not want to use any cloud based speech to text service.